# Jump doesn't work with my movement script in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rider

Jump doesn't work with my movement script in Unity. even though through debugging it shows that my character isgrounded and jump button is being registered. Can anyone help me?

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class Testing : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterController controller;
    public Transform cam;
    public float speed = 6f;
    private float _turnSmoothVelocity;
    private bool _groundedPlayer;
    
    public float turnSmoothTime = 0.1f;
    
 // The player's movement speed.
    public float playerSpeed = 6.0f;

    // The height of the player's jump.
    public float jumpHeight = 1.0f;

    // The value of gravity.
    public float gravityValue = -9.81f;

    // A reference to the player's transform component.
    private Transform _playerTransform;
    
    // The player's current velocity.
    private Vector3 _playerVelocity;
    
    void Start()
    {
        _playerTransform = transform;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        _groundedPlayer = controller.isGrounded;
        
        var horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        var vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        var direction = new Vector3(horizontal, 0f, vertical).normalized;

        if (direction.magnitude >= 0.1f)
        {
            var targetAngle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.x, direction.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg + cam.eulerAngles.y;
            var angle = Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y, targetAngle, ref _turnSmoothVelocity, turnSmoothTime);
            
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, angle, 0f);

            var moveDir = Quaternion.Euler(0f, targetAngle, 0f) * Vector3.forward;
            controller.Move(moveDir.normalized * (speed * Time.deltaTime));
        }
        


        // If the player presses the jump button and they are grounded,
        // give them an upward velocity.
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && _groundedPlayer)
        {
            Debug.Log("Grounded player && jump button pressed"); 
            _playerVelocity.y += Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -3.0f * gravityValue);
        }

        // Apply gravity to the player.
        _playerVelocity.y += gravityValue * Time.deltaTime;

        // Move the player again, this time taking gravity into account.
        controller.Move(_playerVelocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

I tried changing the _playerVelocity.y by adding my gravityValue * time.deltaTime. I expected this to propel my player in to the air but it doesn't do that.

I've used this way of jumping before and it is only not working this time.

Answer (score 0):

Just had to add this to the script:

```cs
if (_groundedPlayer && _playerVelocity.y < 0)
        {
            _playerVelocity.y = 0f;
        }
```